# Storage of std::promise<R&>: "communicate objects"

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, promise, future

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise says that the first specialisation (2) `std::promise<R&>` is "used to communicate objects between threads". However, I don't know how use this functionality and cannot find any documentation anywhere online. My concern specifically is about storage. If I use `std::promise<R&>`, where is the object I pass in stored?

According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise/set_value , ...

- ... `std::promise<R>` has:

  - `set_value(const R &value)`,
  - `set_value(R &&value)`.
- ... `std::promise<R&>` has only:

  - `set_value(R &value)`.

I really think these signatures are odd. I would have expected the right-value reference variant to be part of `std::promise<R&>` as this one is "used to communicate objects between threads". Communicating an object to another thread sounds like "move it into the associated state, such that the other thread can read it from of the associated state (preventing the object to be destructed as the thread that produced it exits)". However, the value seems to be passed in by reference, instead of moved in. Now what happens if the thread exits?

What is the correct way to communicate objects (instead of primitives) between threads with future/promise? What is a good example using the `std::promise<R&>` specialisation?

Comment: Take a look to boost. https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.thread-futures-and-promises
More of the c++ improvements from some years ago comes from boost.

Comment: You can see reference as syntax sugar of pointer, so these clases could work as if it store pointers. But rvalue-references (&&) in other hand, means that the object is copied in another object. If the original object holds pointers, this object could'nt delete these pointers, because they are now owned by other copy (it's said that the passed object gets now in invalid state).
Having both & and && assign methods, implies that the promise<R> really do a copy or a move, so it creates a new instance and copy or move from the one you pass. promise<R&> hold pointers and promise<R> holds copies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::promise<R&> a; //stores the reference to R (a pointer with reference semantics)

std::promise<R>  b; //stores an internal R object.
```

Comment: I guess you are right, as simple as it is, you are right. IMO, the documentation on cppreference is misleading. It does not communicate the object, it communicates the reference.